# App launcher icon sizes while publishing your application

Tags: android

What is the size required of App icons 
 while publishing app on google play console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HDPI   :-   72x72
MDPI   :-   48x48
XHDPI  :-   96x96
XXHDPI  :-  144x144
XXXHDPI  :- 196x196
```

Please refere document : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nfyG-WbR1TyyMc71tR1BFmtrHYWYKinESHk0ZYpHYP0/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! It would be even better if you provided the documentation link showing where those numbers come from, as it would help future users.

Answer (score 1):

Console app icon should be like below,

1. Final size: 512px x 512px
2. Format: 32-bit PNG
3. Color space: sRGB
4. Max file size: 1024KB

Recent google changes some policy. Now shape need to be Full square

You will get more information [from here](https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications)

And your launcher icon sizes will be,

HDPI:72x72

MDPI:48x48

XHDPI:96x96

XXHDPI:144x144

XXXHDPI:192x192

Comment: I think that last one should be 192×192, right? (ie. 2 * 96)

Answer (score 0):

The size should be 512x512.
More information [here](https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications)

Answer (score 0):

For publishing app on play store you required

```
app icon 512*512
app banner 1024*500
```

or you can make app icon online [hear](https://makeappicon.com/)